# Golang: convert slices into map

Tags: go, maps, slice

Is there an easy/simple means of converting a slice into a map in Golang? Like converting an array into hash in perl is easy to do with simple assignment like `%hash = @array`
this above will convert all the elements in the array into a hash, with keys being even-numbered index elements while the values will be odd-numbered index elements of the array.

In my Go code, I have slices of string and would like to convert it into a map. I am wondering if there is a Go's library code to do this.

```
func main() {
  var elements []string
  var elementMap map[string]string
  elements = []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi"}
}
```

elements slice should be converted into map of strings, `elementMap`.

thanks

Answer (score 36):

Use a for loop:

```
elements = []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi"}
elementMap := make(map[string]string)
for i := 0; i < len(elements); i +=2 {
    elementMap[elements[i]] = elements[i+1]
}
```

<kbd>[runnable example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DuJfF_wPMV)</kbd>

The standard library does not have a function to do this.

Comment: I feel like we should make a standard library for some of these data structure helpers

Answer (score 9):

There is currently no way to do it the perl way. You just have to iterate the slice, and place the slice elements in your map, e.g. as the map's key:

```
func main() {
    var elements []string
    var elementMap map[string]string
    elements = []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi"}

    // initialize map
    elementMap = make(map[string]string)

    // put slice values into map
    for _, s := range elements {  
        elementMap[s] = s
        // or just keys, without values: elementMap[s] = ""
    }

    // print map
    for k := range elementMap {
        fmt.Println(k)
    }
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you have to keep one thing in mind: map keys are unique, so if your slice contains duplicate strings you might want to keep count by using a `map[string]int`:

```
func main() {
    var elements []string
    var elementMap map[string]int
    elements = []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi", "fgi", "adi"}

    // initialize map
    elementMap = make(map[string]int)

    // increment map's value for every key from slice
    for _, s := range elements {  
        elementMap[s]++
    }

    // print map
    for k, v := range elementMap {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

And you can always wrap that functionality in a func:

```
func sliceToStrMap(elements []string) map[string]string {
    elementMap := make(map[string]string)
    for _, s := range elements {
        elementMap[s] = s
    }
    return elementMap
}

func sliceToIntMap(elements []string) map[string]int {
    elementMap := make(map[string]int)
    for _, s := range elements {
        elementMap[s]++
    }
    return elementMap
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With generics:

```
func Map[T any, V comparable](src []T, key func(T) V) map[V]T {
    var result = make(map[V]T)
    for _, v := range src {
        result[key(v)] = v
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but it’s more idiomatic to use `K` for the key type and `V` or `T` for the value type

Answer (score 4):

I am just changing the awesome approach of [ngotd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825401/6607562) slightly for preserving the reference.

```
func Map[T any, V comparable](src []T, key func(T) V) map[V]*T {
    var result = make(map[V]T)
    for idx := range src {
        el := &src[idx]
        result[key(el)] = el
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If looking for a library you can use [go-funk](https://github.com/thoas/go-funk). This code may be less performant and not idiomatic in Go until we have Generics.

```
var elements = []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi"}

elementsMap := funk.Map(
    funk.Chunk(elements, 2),
    func(x []string) (string, string) { // Slice to Map
        return x[0], x[1]
    },
)

fmt.Println(elementsMap) // map[abc:def fgi:adi]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-t-33z4aKM_j

Answer (score 2):

Try with range

```
elements := []string{"abc", "def", "fgi", "adi"}
    elementMap := make(map[int]string)
    for i, data := range elements  {
             elementMap[i] = data
        }

fmt.Println(elementMap ) // map[0:abc 1:def 2:fgi 3:adi]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/h6uZn5obLKg

Answer (score 0):

this is same soluation like some sliding windows question answer a much
result slice have more than one map keys:

```golang
    
func zipSlices[T any, V comparable](src []T, size int, keyf func(idx int) V) []map[V]T {

    var results = []map[V]T{}
    total := len(src)
    if total < size {
        return results 
    }
    for idx := 0; idx <= total; idx += size {
        var j int
        var newOne = make(map[V]T)
        for {
            if j >= size {
                j = 0  
                break
            } 

            if idx+j >= total {
                break
            }
            newOne[keyf(j)] = src[idx+j]
            j += 1
        }

        if len(result) > 0 {
            results = append(results , newOne)
        }
    }
    return results 
}
```