# Iterate array of string pairwise to create a map

Tags: go

I have an array of strings whose length is always a multiple of two.

I want to create a map out of this array, so that

```
myarr = ["key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", ...]
```

becomes a map where

```
mymap := mapify(myarr)
mymap['key1'] == "val1"
mymap['key2'] == "val2"
```

In Python I can do this with the following code

```
mymap = {}
for x, y in zip(*[iter(myarr)]*2):
  mymap[x] = y
```

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579502/4636715

Comment: @vahdet Yes! The wording is my problem, I wouldn't have found that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function, something like that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var myarr = []string{"key1", "val1", "key2", "val2"}

func mapify(kv []string) map[string]string {
    mymap := make(map[string]string)

    for i := 0; i+1 <= len(kv); i = i + 2 {
        mymap[kv[i]] = kv[i+1]
    }

    return mymap
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myarr)
    fmt.Println(mapify(myarr))
}
```

Outputs

> ```
> [key1 val1 key2 val2]
> map[key1:val1 key2:val2]
> ```

[Try it here](https://goplay.space/#rUPRdlHO55u)

Comment: Ah, nice, so the iteration is similar to how it would have been done in C.

Comment: You will find that go is often similar to C in that matter. The main differences are that the syntax is more modern and the standard library is much better